# ComboBox Clear Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am writing a script where I have a `Userform` with three `ComboBox`. I want the contents of `ComboBox3` to depend on what the user inputs in `ComboBox2`. I have done so by creating an index for the contents of `ComboBox2` and using the `Select Case` function in order to populate `ComboBox3`. This is working fine.

When the `UserForm` is initialized, `ComboBox3` is frozen until the user inputs something in `ComboBox2`. However, I want `ComboBox3` to become empty and re-freeze whenever the user, after inputting something in `ComboBox2`, erases its contents again. I have tried to do this with the following code:

```
If ComboBox2 = "" Then
      ComboBox3 = "" And ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End If
```

This giver me a "Type Mismatch" error message. I have tried the following, and it works:

```
 If ComboBox2 = "" Then
          ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    End If
```

However, it only re-freezes `ComboBox3` and I really would need it to be empty.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `ComboBox3 = "" And ComboBox3.Enabled = False` Wrong syntax, write these two statement on two different lines and remove the `And`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using `And` incorrectly

If you want it to be on the same line then use

```
If ComboBox2 = vbNullString Then
    ComboBox3 = vbNullString: ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End If
```

If you're not that fussed about the code format use

```
If ComboBox2 = vbNullString Then
    ComboBox3 = vbNullString
    ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End If
```

Also it's better to use `vbNullString` instead of empty quotes